# Read a CSV file and convert it to java objects n lines at a time

Tags: java, spring, csv, java-8, opencsv

I'm trying to read a CSV file and map it to java POJO, using `OpenCSV`. Following is my sample csv class, and `Student.java` is my POJO file

**StudentData.csv**

```
name, rollno, department, result, cgpa
amar, 42, cse, pass, 8.6
rohini, 21, ece, fail, 3.2
aman, 23, cse, pass, 8.9
rahul, 45, ee, fail, 4.6
pratik, 65, cse, pass, 7.2
raunak, 23, me, pass, 9.1
suvam, 68, me, pass, 8.2
```

**readFile() function**

```
    public List<Student> readFile() 
    { 
  
        // Hashmap to map CSV data to  
        // Bean attributes. 
        Map<String, String> mapping = new 
                      HashMap<String, String>(); 
        mapping.put("name", "Name"); 
        mapping.put("rollno", "RollNo"); 
        mapping.put("department", "Department"); 
        mapping.put("result", "Result"); 
        mapping.put("cgpa", "Pointer"); 
  
        // HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy 
        // for Student class 
        HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<Student> strategy = 
             new HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy<Student>(); 
        strategy.setType(Student.class); 
        strategy.setColumnMapping(mapping); 
  
        // Create castobaen and csvreader object 
        CSVReader csvReader = null; 
        try { 
            csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader 
            ("D:\\EclipseWorkSpace\\CSVOperations\\StudentData.csv")); 
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        CsvToBean csvToBean = new CsvToBean(); 
  
        // call the parse method of CsvToBean 
        // pass strategy, csvReader to parse method 
        List<Student> list = csvToBean.parse(strategy, csvReader); 
  
        return list; // I want to read and return 10 at a time
    }
```

**calling method**

```
    public void foo(){
    
    List<Student> students;
    do{
       students = readFile(); // requirement: should return a  list of 10
       sysout(students);
    }while(!students.isEmpty)
    }
```

But I want to read the CSV file `n` lines at a time, and map it to the list of objects.
(Assume my file has 100 records, and I want to read 10 rows at a time into a list)

Comment: You just create a loop that iterates over the whole file, and have a counter inside that counts to 10 and then resets

Comment: @BenjaminM I've updated my question. In the second iteration, how to skip the first `n` lines and start to read from the `(n+1)th` line

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```java
String[] line; // this will contain all columns of a single line in the csv file
int counter = 0;
List<String[]> chunk = new ArrayList<>();
while ((line = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
  counter++;
  
  // do something with the line, for example:
  chunk.add(line);

  if(counter == 10) {
    counter = 0; // reset counter

    // do something when counter reached 10, for example:
    System.out.println(chunk);
    chunk.clear();
  }
}

if(counter > 0) {
  // do something if counter could not be reset, for example:
  System.out.println(chunk); // remaining items
}
```

The last `if(counter > 0)` statement could be useful, if you want the counter for example to count to 10, but you got 15 lines in the csv file. So you can run some code for the remaining lines.

Answer (score 0):

I made the solution using your code as the start point.

I wrote a filter to check out the number of lines to skip and number of lines to return.

```
class LineNumberFilter implements CsvToBeanFilter {

private final int skip;

private final int lines;

private int counter;

public LineNumberFilter(int skip, int lines) {
    this.skip = skip;
    this.lines = lines;
    counter = 0;
}

public boolean allowLine(String[] line) {
    counter++;
    
    return counter >= skip && counter < (skip + lines);
}
```

And to use it, you have to pass the paramters as below to skip 2 lines and to return 2 lines.

```
return csvToBean.parse(strategy, csvReader, new LineNumberFilter(2,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using univocity's csv parser for [java](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_tutorial#using-annotations-to-map-your-java-beans). It supports mapping to java POJOs through annotations.
[Here's](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison) a performance comparison of univocity vs other csv parsers